# Unity find and delete all files named "Delete This File.txt"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity package with my folder structure pre-setup, but meant to be empty, in order to export the folders I put a file "Delete This File.txt" into every bottom folder in the structure to allow unity to export the folders, but I want to write a script that runs on startup which deletes these files, but i can't seem to get the script to find all the files throughout the various folders. How do i do this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup {
    static Startup()
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("Assets/")) {

            if (file == "Delete This File.txt") {
                Debug.Log (file);
            } else {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please include the code you've tried. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @smead I can add my code but my code doesnt produce an error, it just doesnt search all folders for that file.

Comment: In your case, "File" will contain the literal path as well as the file name. Change file== "Delete This File.txt" to Path.GetFileName(file)=="Delete This File.txt" and you should be good to go. Only thing is you may want to change your GetFiles to a full literal path @"c:\Assets\" if you have any problems

Comment: You need to call Startup recursively on items returned by Directory.GetFiles() which are themselves directory.  That' how you can descend a directory hierarchy.  An example is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Yes - your code will only delete one directory. You can feed it a list of paths, or call recursive to walk directory tree if you need to delete from more than one path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering that Directory.EnumerateFiles wasn't an option for me I tried the same method with the get files, and found a solution that works. This code not only deletes the text file but the meta file that is associated with it, counting the number of times a text file was deleted and informing me how many were deleted in the log.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

/*   Project Name : Ember Guard
 *    Script Name : RemoveDeleteFile
 *    Script Path : Assets/Editor/RemoveDeleteFile.cs
 *  Script Author : FaalFaazDov || Raisltin M. Thoreson
 *     Created On : 29/08/2016 14:24
 *    Modified On : N/A
 *        Version : 0.0.1Alpha
 */

 /*************************************************************************
 *
 * Biophase Entertainment
 * __________________
 *
 *  [2016] Biophase Entertainment
 *  All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * NOTICE:  All information contained herein is, and remains
 * the property of Biophase Entertainment and its suppliers,
 * if any.  The intellectual and technical concepts contained
 * herein are proprietary to Biophase Entertainment
 * and its suppliers and may be covered by Canadian and Foreign Patents,
 * patents in process, and are protected by trade secret or copyright law.
 * Dissemination of this information, reproduction of this material or attempting
 * to read the content of these files is strictly forbidden unless prior written
 * permission is obtained from Biophase Entertainment.
 *
 */

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup {

    static Startup()
    {

        int x = 0;

        string path = Application.dataPath;

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles (path, "Delete This File.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string f in files) {

            File.Delete (f);
            File.Delete (f + ".meta");

            x++;

        }

        string fm;

        if (x == 1) {
            fm = "file";
        } else {
            fm = "files";
        }

        Debug.Log ("Deleted " + x + " " + fm + ".");

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution. The bad side is that it will load every file it finds in the memory instead of one by one. So, if you have large files, you will probably run out if memory especially on mobile devices. Since this is just a text file, that should be fine. If these are large files then you might need need to use another solution. Happy coding!

Comment: No need to keep a counter. files.Length is the total number of files found (and *2 to count the deleted)

Comment: that is true, but I wanted to count how many files were deleted as opposed to how many files there were, It would find all the files, i made my own counter to ensure that all files got deleted without having to look for them.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes are required in your code

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup {
static Startup()
{
    // unfortunately this is not available in NET 3.5
    // foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles.....
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("Assets", "Delete This File.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
    {
         Debug.Log (file);
         // File.Delete(file);      
    }
}
```

This approach uses the overload of `Directory.GetFiles` that takes the initial directory, the pattern to search for and the option to search all subdirectory of the root. The resulting strings are the full filenames to delete.

Also, in NET 4.0,  there is a better option with Directory.EnumerateFiles as explained by [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Comment: Unity is informing me that System.IO does not cobtain a definition for EnumerateFiles. Am I missing a namespace that contains EnumerateFiles.

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is in .NET 4. Unity uses .NET 3.5. This shouldn't work.

Comment: Ahh, well, you have catched me. I don't use unity in my works. Initially I answerd with GetFiles but then changed mind to show the better way available in NET 4.0. Should go back but the OP already answered by itself

Comment: That's fine. I suggest saw you did. +1

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the combination of `Directory.GetFiles`,`Directory.GetDirectories` and `FileInfo` classes. I modified Microsoft's RecursiveFileProcessor code [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) and added `FileInfo` and an `if` statement to make it find all files named "`Delete This File.txt`" and delete them.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Startup 
{
    static Startup()
    {
        ProcessDirectory("Assets/");
    }

    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string filePath in fileEntries)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (fileInfo.Name == "Delete This File.txt")
            {
                ProcessFile(filePath);
            }
        }

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
        }
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here.
    public static void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        Debug.Log("Processed file " + path);

        //Delete File
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I just figured it out, with considerably less code.

Comment: You should post the solution then accept it as answer if it is better than the solutions here. It will help other people and will mark this post to be closed

Comment: Just finished posting it.